# IE 6 - Datepicker not displayed properly - half shown half blank

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, datepicker

can some one help me with this

Problem: the datepicker is not displaying properly, it is half seen
and half not like faded or washed away paper
             it works on every browser i tested even IE 6 on some
machines but other which use IE 6 have this
             problem. below is the screen shot of how it looks.

image link:
           http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/3793/errordatepicker.jpg

using :
          jquery 1.3
          jquery UI 1.7.2
          IE 6
          datepicker theme : smoothness
          using animation effect
                         showAnim: 'drop',
                         showOptions: {direction: 'up' }

you time and help is appreciated
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try without any show effects, does it render ok then? The picker uses an iframe mask in ie6 but I am not sure how this plays out with the show effects. i always disable the effects as they all look bad in ie6.

If this does not work can you show what markup you have on that page and can you try to recreate the issue at jsbin.com or pastebin.me. The screenshot is pretty weak and it is hard to see what is happening.

Ie6 should use the iframe mask by default.

Comment: how do i apply this?
just doing this $(function() {$('.datepickerclass').bgiframe();});
will add the bgiframe on the clendar text box but not on the datepicker itself??? thanks for you help

Comment: hey just tried it out without the show effects and it worked, thank you for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused from some of the oddities of IE6 and CSS. Is there a full example you add a link to?

Comment: it wont be possible to add a link to it, sorry for that, thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

this is solved, 
the problem was the animation's show effect
(showAnim: 'drop', showOptions: {direction: 'up' } )

just removed it as redsquare suggested and it worked

the effects used to work in IE6 for some machines and not for some machines so just removed the effects

thanks everyone for you time and help
fossil